# Yii2 REST API find by field

Tags: yii2, yii-rest

This is api url.

> /api/web/v1/users/123

Find user by id. How to change rule to find by `token`, not by `id`?

Here is a rule:

```
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => ['v1/users'],
                'tokens' => [
                    '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'

                   // this does not work  
                   // '{token}' => '<token:\\w+>'
                ],
            ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `{id}` defined as a token is the one used by the built in [yii\rest\ViewAction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-viewaction.html) which code is this:

```
class ViewAction extends Action
{
    /**
     * Displays a model.
     * @param string $id the primary key of the model.
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveRecordInterface the model being displayed
     */
    public function run($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        if ($this->checkAccess) {
            call_user_func($this->checkAccess, $this->id, $model);
        }

        return $model;
    }
}
```

`$this->findModel($id)` is defined under [yii\rest\Action](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-action.html) and it find models using their primary key(s). If you need to use a different token like `{token}` and find your model within a different attribute than its primary key then you'll need to override the view action inside your controller.

Here is an example that should work when adding `'{token}' => '<token:\\w+>'` to your rules:

```
class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    ...
    public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['view']);
        return $actions;
    }

    public function actionView($token){
        $modelClass = $this->modelClass;
        $model = $modelClass::find()->where(['token' => $token])->one();

        if ($model === null)
            throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException("Uknown user having $token as token");

        return $model;
    }

}
```

Also note that you will need to change your [$patterns](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html#$patterns-detail) to support the new inroduced one. Your final rules may look like this:

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
        'controller' => ['v1/users'],  
        'tokens' => [
            '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>',
            '{token}' => '<token:\\w+>'
        ]
        'patterns' => [
            'PUT,PATCH {id}' => 'update',
            'DELETE {id}' => 'delete',
            // {token} is assigned to $token when redirecting to view
            'GET,HEAD {token}' => 'view',
            'POST' => 'create',
            'GET,HEAD' => 'index',
            '{id}' => 'options',
            '' => 'options',
        ],
    ],
]
```

Comment: Now I have `Bad Request. Missing required parameters: token`.  
If enable `{token} => <token:\\w+>` in rule then 404. 
What's wrong?

Comment: I just updated. that happens because patterns is using `'GET,HEAD {id}' => 'view'` by default. you need to change it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Salem Ouerdani